# Point layer data frequency within a raster layer

Tags: raster, point, statistics

I need to determine which land cover has the highest/lowest number of points from a delegate point layer.

I have the land cover classified and a separate key (i.e. 1-saltwater) -- How can I find how many points are within each land cover type?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Frequency within an "Easter" layer didn't make any sense, so I changed it to "raster". Please [Edit] the Question to specify what software you are using and what you have attempted so far, since there are a number of ways to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which soft you use to work but in QGIS is very easy to solve this task

1 vectorize your land cover map. To do this, you should use the "r.to.vect" tool.

2 Count the points present in each polygon using the "Count points in polygons" tool.

3 Finally, you should copy the database to a spreadsheet soft like Excel or Calc and complete the sums.

Sometimes, it is necessary to fix the geometry of the vectorized map. To do this you should use the "Fix geometry" of the Qgis Toolbox.

I hope these process steps could solve your problem.